# Highstock - Pulling data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I understand there are many similar questions related to this topic on SO however, I was unsuccessful at implementing what I am trying to do so I am writing a question here. Please understand that I am very new.

So, basically, using the Highstock - the basic graph which can be found here http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line, I want to import the data from an JSON file named Json1.json. How would I do this? http://jsfiddle.net/x0g8hL0e/1/

In the JavaScript, I have written

```
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('Json1.json', function (data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Pressure'
            },

        });
    });

});
```

Also, is it possible to just see the 24 hour format instead of a year-long?

P.S, Json data is formatted in this way

```
[
{"Pressure": 1},
{"Pressure": 5},
{"Pressure": 3},
{"Pressure": 2},
{"Pressure": 4}
}]
```

Comment: Where is your "Json1.json" file located at?

Comment: Your json data needs a timestamp value. Example: `1226966400000`

Comment: @YuWu, at the same folder as the index

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez so in a format of {"label": value, timestamp} ?

Comment: If you see http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/, you will find that the jsonp data has `[1227052800000,12.33]`: where the first item is a timestamp and the second item is the value.

Check the jsonp data: https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=jQuery19107105389786884189_1447886162668&_=1447886162669

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez , thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should process your data, so it will be in a format that is accepted by Highcharts. It can be (as described in [API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<line>.data)):

1. An array of numerical values.
2. An array of arrays with 2 values.
3. An array of objects with named values.

Other option is to use an array with [`keys`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<line>.keys) defined.

If you want to use e.g. 1st data fromat, then you could go through your JSON and create an array of numerical values with values taken out of each object, from `Pressure` property.

```
$(function () {

    //$.getJSON('Json1.json', function (data) {
    // simulate JSON data
    var data = [{
        "Pressure": 1
    }, {
        "Pressure": 5
    }, {
        "Pressure": 3
    }, {
        "Pressure": 2
    }, {
        "Pressure": 4
    }],
        processedData = [];
    // process the data to match one of formats required by Highcharts - an array of numberical values
    // see: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<line>.data
    Highcharts.each(data, function(d) {
        processedData.push(d.Pressure);
    });
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pressure'
        },

        series: [{
            data: processedData
        }]

    });
    //});

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83gsyaLu/)

For basic information about Highcharts you could see [General Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs)

Comment: Hi, so I see that you have inputted the data into the var data  instead of pulling the data from JSON file. A situation I have is that, I have a Json1.json file that has hundreds of data. Is there a way to pull it from here? or do I have to declare them under the var data just the way you have ?

Comment: @axchink When you have data from a JSON, then just remove `data` variable assignment and use the JSON returned from `$.getJSON` instead. Example that will not work in JSFiddle because of lack of Json1.json file, but should work for you if your JSON is accessible: http://jsfiddle.net/mc84qte6/